# Change design of powerView Excel 2013

Tags: excel, powerview

Can I change the design of the pie chat color to custom color and change the design of the filters in powerView?

Answer (score 1):

You can not set custom colors for charts, you have to chose from one of the "Themes" that is provided. Can you expand on what you mean by changing the design of the filters?

Comment: What do you mean by filters? slicers? The pie chart legend?